# Multi-File Version of vc-state

Tags: version-control, emacs, elisp, visual-c++

Have anyone of you Emacs-Lisp hackers written a multi-file version of `vc-state`? With multi-file I mean a signature of kind

```
vc-multi-state (file-list)
```

that returns a list of the elements returned by `vc-state`. The trivial implementation of just mapping `vc-state` over a list of filenames is not enough as this cost far too much file in list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `(vc-call-backend backend 'dir-status dir callback)` and `(vc-call-backend backend 'dir-status-files dir files default callback)`